# Simple recursive sort algorithm which hard to understand

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int N = 100000;
void sort(int* a, int lo, int hi)
{
    int i = lo;
    if (lo >= hi)
        return;
    for (int j = hi, mode = 1; i < j; mode > 0 ? j-- : i++)
        if (a[i] > a[j])
        {           
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
            mode = -mode;            
        }
    sort(a, lo, i - 1); 
    sort(a, i + 1, hi);
}
bool check(int* a)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        if (a[i] < a[i - 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int a[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = (i * 17 + 107) % 10;
    sort(a, 0, N - 1);
    cout << (check(a) ? "correct" : "incorrect") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I found this sort algorithm but after long time of trying to understand it I couldn't. It looks very simple and short. I think that it can be proved through invariant that any element of `a[lo:i]` is less than any element of `a[j:hi]` but I can't prove that statement holds true after every iteration of loop (after `j--` or `i++`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a modified version of [quicksort](http://v2.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/sequencing/sort-algorithms/quicksort/) with 1st element as the pivot.

The algorithm basically does the following:

It has two pointers, `i` starting at `0`, and `j` starting at `length-1`.

It keeps decrementing `j` untill `a[j] < a[i]`. At this point it swaps their values.
After this, `j` stays at that value, and `i` starts incrementing again untill `a[j] < a[i]`. At this point it again swaps their values and now again `j` starts decrementing.

Hence if you see, every comparison is being done with the 1st element. After the loop ends, the 1st element lands up in its correct place.

Comment: Tricky partition procedure from quick sort) Thanks for explanation

Comment: Yes its implementation is very confusing.